# SVG tags in hamlet shakespearean (yesod/haskell) templates?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

Is there a way to include  tags in hamlet? If not, what are the workarounds/alternatives?

Comment: Try it and see what happens

Comment: Huh odd. I was getting a compile time error earlier `"Exception when trying to run compile-time code: …"` but now I realize that only happens when I have attributes on the tag. `<svg>` compiles but `<svg height = "50" width = "500">` does not.

Comment: Weird. Probably worth reporting it as a bug. I can't think of any reason why svg tags should be handled any differently from any other non-selfclosing html tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include it like any other tags. Don't put spaces before and after equals sign.

`<svg height="50" width="500">`